# Pass hits from django-hitcount to model serializer

Tags: django

I am using `django-hitcount` to track hits on my model. I would like to pass the data from the hits to an API through a serializer. This is how i am doing it currently on my serializer using serializer method field but i am getting nulls

`hotel_hits = serializers.SerializerMethodField()`

```
"policies",
'hotel_type_id',
'hotel_hits',
```

```
 def get_hotel_hits(self, obj):
        try:
            return obj.hit_count.hits
        except:
            pass
```

What could i be doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I want to answer this question as i can see it has been asked in several places and no one has been able to answer it.
You first must set the model where you are passing hits counts as follows

```
class MyModel(models.Model, HitCountMixin):
      //rest of the code goes here
```

Then on the serializer where you want pass hits information use ```serializerFieldMethod`` as follows

`hotel_hits = serializers.SerializerMethodField()`

```
'hotel_hits',
```

```
 def get_hotel_hits(self, obj):
        try:
            return obj.hit_count.hits
        except:
            pass
```

You can get more information on official docs [here](https://django-hitcount.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html#models)
Hope this helps anyone else